# d3.js - chain box with arrow lines

Tags: d3.js

I would like to draw few text box and chain it with arrow lines. I use below code to draw the text box few issues there:

1. text box is black and no text show there.
2. One box is missing, it should be 5 box but only 4 can be seen.
3. how can I add a arrow line to connect each other!

```js
test()
function test() {
  var data = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
  
  width = 800
  height = 600
  margin = 10
  
  //var svg = d3.select("svg");
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
  
  svg.style("border","5px solid red");

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  
  var group = svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(data).enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform',function(d,i) {
        //console.log(i,d);
        return 'translate('+(100*i)+',0)';
      });
  
  var box = group.selectAll('rect')
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      });
  
  box.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", 30)
    .attr("height", 30)
    .attr('font-size',2)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { 
    //console.log(d);
    return 60 + 2*d; 
  })  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. text box is black and no text shown.

You aren't appending any text. Text also can't be appended to a rectangle, so there is no need to apply font properties to a rectangle. Text can be appended to a `g` though. So we can use a parent `g` to hold both rectangle and text. Something like:

```
group.append("rect")...

group.append("text")...
```

The boxes are black because you haven't applied a fill. The default fill is black.

2. One box is missing, it should be 5 box but only 4 can be seen.

This is because when you enter the parent `g` elements, you select all `g` elements.   This includes the one you've already appended (`svg.append("g")`). The enter selection is intended to create elements such that every item in the data array is paired with an element in the DOM. Since you already have a `g` in your selection, the enter selection will only create 4 new ones (representing data array items with indexes 1-4 but not 0).

Instead of `selectAll("g")` you could specify a class name or, in the event you simply want to enter everything and there isn't a need to ever update a selection: `selectAll(null)`. The latter option will always return an empty selection, which will result in the enter selection containing one element per item in the data array.

*Note, that the parent's datum is passed to appended children automagically, there is no need to use the .data method to pass this onward unless you are handling nested data.*

Here's a snippet addressing issues in one and two:

```js
test()
function test() {
  var data = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
  
  width = 800
  height = 600
  margin = 10

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .style("border","5px solid red");
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  
  var group = svg.selectAll(null)
      .data(data).enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform',function(d,i) {
        return 'translate('+(40*i)+',0)';
      });
  
  group
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", 30)
    .attr("height", 30)
    .attr("fill","yellow")

  group.append("text")
    .text(function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("y", 20)
    .attr("x", 15)
    .attr("text-anchor","middle");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

*I also changed `svg` to refer to the parent `g`, the one with the margin applied. Before the `g` with the margin remained unused, along with the margin. I also modified the spacing to keep everything in view.*

3. how can I add a arrow line to connect each other!

This can be done in many ways and really is a separate issue from the others, so I'll only quickly demonstrate one of many options. I'll modify your data structure a bit so that each datum has positional data and then add arrows using SVG markers:

```js
test()
function test() {
  var data = [{name:"a"},{name:"b"},{name:"c"},{name:"d"},{name:"e"}]
  
  width = 800
  height = 600
  margin = 10

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .style("border","5px solid red")
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    
  svg.append("defs")
    .append("marker")
    .attr("id","pointer")
    .attr("markerWidth", 10)
    .attr("markerHeight", 10)
    .attr("orient","auto")
    .attr("refY", 5)
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z")
    
  
  var group = svg.selectAll(null)
      .data(data).enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform',function(d,i) {
        d.x = 40*i+15, d.y=30;
        return 'translate('+(40*i)+',0)';
      });
  
  group
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", 30)
    .attr("height", 30)
    .attr("fill","yellow")

  group.append("text")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
    .attr("y", 20)
    .attr("x", 15)
    .attr("text-anchor","middle");
    
    
   links = [
     {source: data[0], target: data[1]},
     {source: data[0], target: data[2]}
   ]
   
   svg.selectAll(null)
     .data(links)
     .enter()
     .append("path")
     .attr("d", function(d) {
        var midX = (d.source.x+d.target.x)/2;
        return "M"+d.source.x+" "+d.source.y+"Q"+midX+" "+200+" "+d.target.x+" "+(d.target.y+6);
     })
     .attr("fill","none")
     .attr("stroke","black")
     .attr("stroke-width",1)
     .attr("marker-end","url(#pointer)");
  
  

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```